# BIT_COUNT(hash1^hash2) interprets the result of hash1^hash2 as a string

Tags: mysql, sql, binary, hex

So:

b'1010' ^ b'0000' = 1010

if I do:
`BIT_COUNT(b'1010' ^ b'0000')` I get the right result (2)

But if I select the same values from the table (binary fields)
`BIT_COUNT(hash1 ^ hash2)` I get the wrong result

Even if I make the fields hexadecimal in the table and try to cast them to binary and then count the bits, I still get the same wrong result:

```
BIT_COUNT(CONV(hex_hash1, 16, 2) ^ CONV(hex_hash2, 16, 2))
```

Another example of weird behaviour, if I do the following query:

```
SELECT 
    BIT_COUNT(CONV('b', 16, 2) ^ CONV('d', 16, 2))
```

I get 9 as a result, when it should've been 2. From what I can see the result is processed as a string, I tried CAST(), CONV() and so on, and none of it works.

Anyone knows why?

(here is my environment)

```
'innodb_version', '5.7.23'
'protocol_version', '10'
'slave_type_conversions', ''
'tls_version', 'TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2'
'version', '5.7.23-log'
'version_comment', 'Source distribution'
'version_compile_machine', 'x86_64'
'version_compile_os', 'Linux'
```

Comment: How are you getting the data back out for use in `BIT_COUNT`?

Comment: Also `b'1010' ^ b'0000' = 1010` as you're asking for a XOR. The number of bits is 2. The result is not 2.

Comment: @tadman I didn't quite get what you mean. I select the field from the table, and in the table the field is declared as binary.

Comment: @tadman you're right about `b'1010' ^ b'0000' = 1010`, I got that wrong. But  `BIT_COUNT(b'1010' ^ b'0000') = 2` is the right result I think.

Comment: Remember that a `BINARY` column is not a series of bits or a binary value of some sort, it's just a byte string as far as MySQL is concerned. It's the light-weight version of `BLOB`.